# why PARALLEL is used in select query whats tgge purpose here?

Tags: sql, oracle

Why `PARALLEL` is used in select query, what's the purpose here?

can anyone pls explain

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(lds_order_status, 16) */
    PO_NO  from lds_order_status
where status = 'CLOSED' group by
    PO_NO order by
    PO_NO
```

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_parallel_hint.htm

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-D25225CE-2DCE-4D9F-8E82-401839690A6E). Why it is used here is a question to the author. In general, this hint will not provide much benefit on simple consumption, because sending data to the client is serial

Comment: @astentx, that is not true. Sending data to the  client is Fetching, which is the last step of any SQL. If the table is big enough, and you are retrieving a lot of its records, the EXECUTION phase will go faster. Also grouping and sorting are operations which can get a lot of benefit from parallel query

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the `PARALLEL` hint is to run the query using parallel threats. It basically works like this:

- The query is split into different processes. One master process called QC or Query Coordinator handles the communication between itself (Parent) and the PQ slaves or child processes.
- You use PARALLEL QUERY in situations when you can afford CPU and I/O consumption in order to speed up the result of a query
- It is commonly used in Data Warehouse or ETL applications. Sorting and grouping over big tables can get a real boost in performance with Parallel Query.

In your case, the query is using the HINT `PARALLEL` over one table with a specific degree or parallelism ( the number afterwards )

`/*+ PARALLEL(lds_order_status, 16) */` The parallel will affect the table with alias lds_order_status and it will apply a degree up to 16 ( 16 slave processes ). I mean, it will use up to 16, but it could be less.

It would be worth it for you to read the documentation about the HINT and how it works in different scenarios.